# How to decrease or remove the lines that are between the paragraphs with itextsharp?

Tags: c#, itext

I have the following code in which I create a pdf with itextsharp. I leave you an example:

```
byte[] pdf = null;
using (MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
//Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 65, 15);//izquierda,derecha,superior, inferior
float myWidth = 227f;
float myHeight = 842f;


var pgSize = new Rectangle(myWidth, myHeight);
using (var pdfDoc = new Document(pgSize, 2, 2, 1, 30))
{
    var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
    table.WidthPercentage = 100;
    table.SpacingBefore = 10f;
    //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
    table.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
    widths = new float[] { 10, 80, 10 };
    table.SetWidths(widths);

    cell = new PdfPCell();
    Chunk chunk = new Chunk("", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK));
    cell = new PdfPCell();
    cell.Border = 0;
    cell.PaddingBottom = 0;
    cell.AddElement(chunk);
    table.AddCell(cell);


    Image image = Image.GetInstance(img_firma);
    image.ScaleAbsolute(185f, 105f);
    cell = new PdfPCell(image);
    cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
    cell.PaddingBottom = 0;
    //cell.FixedHeight = 100;
    cell.Border = 0;
    //cell.AddElement(image);
    table.AddCell(cell);

    cell = new PdfPCell();
    chunk = new Chunk("", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK));
    cell = new PdfPCell();
    cell.Border = 0;
    cell.PaddingBottom = 0;
    cell.AddElement(chunk);
    table.AddCell(cell);


    Paragraph parrafo1 = new Paragraph();//titulo
    parrafo1.Add(new Chunk("Hello", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
    parrafo1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Paragraph parrafo2 = new Paragraph();
    parrafo2.Add(new Chunk("Bye", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
    parrafo2.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
```

//down here I try to remove the lines that are in between,
down here I try to remove the lines that are in between with SetLeading

```
    Paragraph phrase = new Paragraph();
    phrase.SetLeading(0, 0);
    phrase.Add(parrafo1);
    phrase.Add(parrafo2);

    cell = new PdfPCell();
    //Paragraph valorcelda = new Paragraph();
    //valorcelda.Add(new Chunk(text_pie, FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 7, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
    //valorcelda.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    cell.PaddingTop = 0;
    cell.Border = 0;
    cell.FixedHeight = 0;
    cell.Colspan = 3;
    cell.AddElement(phrase);
    table.AddCell(cell);

    pdfDoc.Add(table);



    pdfDoc.Close();
    pdf = stream.ToArray();
}
}
```

but when the pdf is generated, it shows the texts hello and bye very separated. I have tried to do it with SetLeading, but it doesn't work. How could I solve this?

[image]

Comment: Just for clarification, you are using the deprecated ITextSharp and not the recommended IText 7?

Comment: @JohnG itextsharp.xmlworker version 5.5.13.1

Comment: Unfortunately, the posted code is incomplete and does not reproduce what you describe. I recommend creating a complete MRE [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)    In the MRE I would remove the code with the table as it does not appear to relate to your question. Also, I recommend you specify the specific libraries you are using. I get an error on `Font.NORMAL` using the posted code. Can you post the complete code that recreates the issue?

Comment: From what I can see, try adding the leading to the paragraph like… `parrafo2.Leading = XX;`

Comment: edit the question, I put the most complete code

Comment: @JohnG thanks, that's the solution. You can place it to approve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell in my tests…the line…

```
phrase.SetLeading(0, 0);
```

Is not doing what you expect. In my limited research it appears this should set the leading but as noted here, it does not appear to be setting the leading as expected.

Is what will work, is setting the leading to the individual paragraph like…

```
parrafo2.Leading = XX;
```